# Fill in the blanks

Tags: problem-solving

I got that quiz the other day and struggled to solve it.

you have a list of integers and operators:

```
1, 1, 6, 3, 9, 0, 8, 0, 2, 9, (, ), +, +, -, =
```

You have to use every item of that list exactly once.
Fill the blanks to get an equation. There are already two operators at the correct places.

```
_ _ _ _ * _ _ / _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Please don't tell me the solution(s), but rather how you would go about such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first though was stuff*0=0/stuff but that doesn't work because there are only two spaces between * and /  Those two spaces have to get digits.  Now note there are ten digits and eight symbols.  There are four blanks before the *  What can the pattern of digits and symbols be?  What does each pattern leave over for the ending ten spaces?  The parentheses can go against other symbols.

I believe problems like this should promise you a unique solution, but I have a whole family of them.  Some might disallow it.  I suspect my family does not exhaust the possibilities, but it makes me less interested in searching.